# Objects filter with multiple choices in Django

Tags: django

I want to get **People objects who work as ADMIN** and **People objects who work as EDITOR** in a Model People have field: role.

My Model:

```
GroupRoles = (
    ('admin', 'Admin'),
    ('editor', 'Editor'),
    ('normal', 'Normal'),
)

class People(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=GroupRoles, default='normal')
```

What i did:

```
People.objects.filter(group=group, role={'admin', 'editor'})
```

But I get no object in queryset:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
People.objects.filter(group=group, role__in=['admin', 'editor'])
```